# How to create a picture that fills in colours based on a matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array in MATLAB in the following format:

```
aa = {[1 2],[2 3],[1 2 3 4 5 6],[5],[1]}
```

Is it possible to create a diagram in this style (i.e. filling in a block colour for each time a number shows up)?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a possible solution based on `pcolor`:

```
aa = {[1 2],[2 3],[1 2 3 4 5 6],[5],[1]};
n_rows = length(aa);
n_columns = max(cell2mat(aa));
m = zeros(n_rows + 1, n_columns + 1);
row = n_rows;
for i=1:n_rows
    m(row, aa{i}) = 1;
    row = row - 1;
end
colormap([1 1 1; 1 0.5 0]);
pcolor(m);
```

it produces following result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since you have vectors with varying lengths in your cell array, you'll need to iterate those in some loop (or alike, see [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) used below). The rest is initializing some matrix with your desired background value, and set all "pixels" inside that matrix to your desired foreground value.

Here's a small code snippet (tested with Octave 5.1.0 and MATLAB Online):

```matlab
aa = {[1 2], [2 3], [1 2 3 4 5 6], [5], [1]}

% Determine needed number of rows and columns
r = size(aa, 2);
c = max(cellfun(@max, aa));

% Initialize and fill matrix
A = 255 * ones(r, c);
for I = 1:r
  A(I, aa{I}) = 128;
end

% Show matrix with some colormap and labels
figure('Position', [300, 300, 800, 400]);
imagesc(A, [0, 255]);
colormap('hot');
set(gca, ...
  'FontSize', 12, ...
  'TickLength', [0 0], ...
  'XTick', [1:c], ...
  'XTickLabel', [repmat('V', c, 1) num2str([1:c].')], ...
  'YTick', [], ...
  'XAxisLocation', 'Top');
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Output]

(Instead of setting proper colors, I just used some grayscale image with a colormap here.)

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's nice, shamelessly reused your code for filling the matrix in my example.